# update part of an xml node stored as ntext

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a very simple data structure with an integer primary key and an "xml" column stored as ntext.  How can I update specific nodes of the xml column stored as ntext?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: If the data looks like XML, smells like XML, behaves like XML - ***why*** aren't you **storing** it as an `XML` datatype?? The XQuery functions work on `XML` datatypes **only** - use the appropriate datatypes!

Comment: I would love to use the XML datatype.  This is a legacy cms so unfortunately modifying the datatype is unfeseeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ntext` data type is problematic to say the least. 
As marc_s wrote in his comments, this type is deprecated, and even if it wasn't, it's the wrong data type to use for storing XML data.

The [XML data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385(v=sql.120).aspx) has been around since at least the 2012 version, and you should really consider changing your database structure to use it instead of the deprecated `ntext`.

If changing the database structure is impossible, then you will have to select the value, try to convert it into a usable type (since `ntext` doesn't even supports the `replace` function), manipulate the data, and then convert it back to `ntext` and update the row.

Comment: This is indeed the route I'm forced down since I cannot change the datatype behind the storage due to circumstances out of my control.